# Rafter supports

Tags: roof, frame

I am building shed rafters from a plan I got off line. The spread is 12ft with rectangle shape and a king post in the center. Not sure of the roof pitch, but the king post is 2ft 8". Someone suggested I put some web supports or struts on sides of king post to the principal rafter for extra brace, since we have snow around 40 psf. The span of principal rafters is about 78" on each side from top to support tie beam at bottom and 12ft across bottom. I am using 1/2 plywood gussets at all joins, on both sides of truss, using 2" 6d common galv nails every 4" and glued
Do you think I really need to worry about adding extra support?
Thanks
Dean

[image]

Comment: Do the plans tell you what their design parameters are for spf?

Comment: There's  plenty of garbage designs on the internet.  If there's no clear evidence of goodness just use them for inspiration.

Comment: Longneck, no spec on spf.

Comment: Jasen, I agree. I will be adding them just for good measure and hopefully some piece of mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for plans to make a W style truss. Much much better than the oldfangled design that you picture in your question. The W style uses a bit more material for the struts but will support the upper rafter in its center zone dramatically increasing the stability and rigidity. The lower chord also gets supported as three segments instead of two.

Comment: The kingpost literally adds nothing structurally. A W adds considerable strength (for the same top and bottom chords) or permits use of less lumber if actually designed.

Comment: Ecnerwal, the king post adds some Stability in strength. Well it may not be much it does add.

Comment: Michael Kara’s, I have Already committed to using this truss design  and made a  jig to build them with. So I think I’ll just add a web piece on the sides of the king post. Any suggestions on what angle I should go? Thank you

Comment: The vernacular "kingpost with struts" goes 45 degrees from the kingpost  for the struts.

Comment: See pages 20 and 25 here. The notes on the Howe truss (page 25) suggest that the angle of the struts should match the angle of the roof for structural efficiency. https://dcstructural.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/TFEC-4-2020-Design-Guide-for-Timber-Roof-Trusses.pdf

Comment: @Dean - Well sorry that you committed to the oldfangled type design. Maybe you should reconsider and modify the jig for a W design more like this one (first picture) https://www.fixr.com/resources/all-about-roof-trusses. You main rafter pieces and lower chord can stay the same. Just the struts need to be modified to get  superior result.

Comment: Ecnerwal, thank you for that information. I was actually going to go 45 deg, but looks like you are saying that both angles should be what top cord angle is, and in this case it's 26.5

Comment: Michael & Ecnerwal, I think I will go with the Kingpost truss, with the one web off each side of the kingpost. It says that design is good for 5 to 8 meters and I am going 12ft which is under 5 meters by 3ft. Would you agree that should be enough? And I was considering going every other truss. So I have 10 total. ends will be supported by siding, so I would skip them. Put webs on the two inside trusses and then skip one on each side and then webs on next ones. So there would be 4 trusses with webs. Thoughts?

Comment: @Dean you came here asking for advice, then reject the advice you've been given. If you were driving on I-71 from Cincinnati to Columbus, and saw a sign stating "80 miles to Louisville", would you continue driving that way just because you'd started out that way, or would you turn around? Additionally, you've asked a new question in your comment. Use the "Ask a question" button instead.

Comment: Freeman, I did not reject anything. Relax man! I just don't want to over kill if not needed. Not everything is as black and white as it looks or sound on here.